# Rails - Why jQuery Doesn't Load After Submitting My Form Remotely

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript, ujs

For the sake of simplicity, I have a form that updates a partial. Nothing special there. Within the partial, I have a jQuery sortable list. Before updating the form, I can drag things around in the list without problem.

However, after I update the list, it's like js isn't reloaded and I have to refresh the whole page to get things rolling again.

I've tried everything, even borrowed the [demo jQuery application from Ryan Bates Esq. over here.](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised?view=asciicast) That doesn't work either after I put some js shizzle in the partial.

I'm sure it's simple but I'm an ajax / jQuery newbie and am really struggling.

View:

```
#test_one
  = render "test_one"
```

partial "test_one"

```
= form_for @location, :remote => true do |f|
  %table
    %tr= collection_select(:location, :type_ids, Type.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => true}, :multiple => true, :class=>"chzn-select")
     %tr
       %td
         %ul#types.unstyled{"data-update-url" => sort_types_locations_url}
           - @types.each do |type|
             = content_tag_for :li, type do
               %span.handle
                 [Drag]
               = type.name
```

update.js.erb

```
$("#test_one").html('<%= escape_javascript render("test_two") %>');
```

And in my controller:

```
  def update
    @location = Location.find(params[:id])
    @types = @location.types.order('location_types.position').limit(2)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @location.update_attributes!(params[:location])
        flash[:notice] = 'Settings updated successfully'
        format.html { redirect_to edit_location_path }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit_access" }
        format.js { render action: "update_access_errors" }
      end
    end
  end
```

And finally in locations.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $('#types').sortable(
      axis: 'y'
      update: ->
        $.post($(this).data('update-url'), $(this).sortable('serialize'))
      )
```

The update works, I get no errors and I have nothing in my console. Am a lot lost with this now - how can I get the js to reload after I update the record?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is, your custom js(about sortable) is loaded on document ready, and won't be fired again once partial updated.

The solution is: wrap your custom js into a function. Call this function when document ready and update happens.

```
# locations.js.coffee
$ ->
  $(document).custom_js()

$.fn.custom_js ->
  $('#types').sortable(
    axis: 'y'
    update: ->
      $.post($(this).data('update-url'), $(this).sortable('serialize'))
    )

# update.js.erb
$("#test_one").html('<%= escape_javascript render("test_two") %>');
$(document).custom_js();
```

Side note about custom js function: No need to wrap all custom codes here, just the part relating to what are going to added/updated by Ajax.

Comment: You've just improved my mood and the mood of others around me ten fold :) Big thanks. Simple wasn't it!

Comment: @simonmorley, my pleasure to be of a bit helpful :)

Comment: @BillyChan thank you man, I was just thinking - when I have a loop where that partial is rendered a hundred times, it means that the code in `update.js.erb` will be called a hundred times as well - this might slow down the application. Just wondering - is there a more efficient solution? Thanks.

Comment: @user984621, I think in your case the above code can't be used directly and need some modification. Some points: 1. I don't think rendering 100+ times is that slow to feel ugly, especially if you have a spinner showing up. 2. the whole loop of html can be composed in server side if really needed.